# Can't Update Record After Sequelize Validation Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm encountering a weird error with a project i'm working on in Node/JS/Express/Sqlite.  I can successfully retrieve the user's details and have an HTML form providing ability to edit the details.  The fields are required fields and are defined in my model like this (first_name as an example):

```
first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: {
          msg: 'A first name is required'
        }
      }
```

Now if I go to edit an existing field with text, and submit the form, the data is updated correctly.

If I remove text from an input box on the form and submit, a sequelize validation error is triggered and error text is shown.  Working fine thus far.

But if I go to replace the empty text from step above with new text (different from the previous value) the form submits, yet the value for this field reverts to the original value.  This will happen for any fields for the user.

Here's an example of what my UPDATE route looks like.  If more code is needed just let me know.

```
/* POST Update Patron */
router.post("/details/:id", function(req, res, next){
  Patron.update(req.body, {
    where: [{
      id: req.params.id
    }]
  })
  .then(patron=>{
    res.redirect("/patrons");
  })
  .catch(function(error){
      if(error.name === "SequelizeValidationError") {
      const patron = Patron.build(req.body);
      const loans = Loan.findAll({where: {patron_id: req.params.id}, include: [{ model: Patron}, {model: Book}]});
      Promise.all([patron, loans]).then(function(data){
        res.render("patron_detail", {patron: data[0], loans: data[1], errors: error.errors})
      })
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(500, error);
    });
  });
```

And here is my PUG/HTML Form for the USER (patron):

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Patron: #{patron.first_name} #{patron.last_name}

  include error

  form(action='/patrons/details/' + patron.id, method="post")
    P 
      label(for='first_name') First name:
      input(id='first_name' name='first_name' type='text' value=patron.first_name)
    p
      label(for='last_name') Last Name:
      input(id='last_name' name='last_name' type='text' value=patron.last_name)
    p
      label(for='address') Address:
      input(id='address' name='address' type='text' value=patron.address)
    p
      label(for='email') Email:
      input(id='email' name='email' type='text' value=patron.email)
    p
      label(for='library_id') Library ID:
      input(id='libary_id' name='library_id' type='text' value=patron.library_id)
    p
      label(for='zip_code') Zip Code:
      input(id='zip_code' name='zip_code' type='text' value=patron.zip_code)
    p
      input(type='submit', value='Update')

  h2 Loan History
  table
   thead
    tr
      th Book
      th Patron
      th Loaned On
      th Return By
      th Returned On
      th Action

    tbody
      if loans.length > 0
        each loan in loans
          tr
            td
              a(href='/books/details/' + loan.Book.id) #{loan.Book.title}
            td
              a(href='/patrons/details/' + loan.Patron.id) #{loan.Patron.first_name} #{loan.Patron.last_name}
            td= loan.loaned_on
            td= loan.return_by
            td= loan.returned_on
            if(!loan.returned_on)
              td
                a.button(href=`/loans/${loan.id}/return`) Return Book
      else
        tr
          td No Loans
```

Comment: share your html form with us

Comment: just added to OP

Comment: you are facing this issue only when submitting your form after any validation error, right? in that case, before processing any data, check your submitted data using console log. More specifically, before running update operation, check your req.body values.

Comment: ok so just did a console.log(req.body) before the update command as you suggested--and everything looks ok, so if i blank out a value, it shows as '', or if i edit it, the value shows correctly in console

Comment: Usually for this type of updating, I use findOneAndUpdate() and it's working perfectly. If form data are correctly submitted, it should work properly. You need to ensure patron.id value are same when updating.

Comment: do you know if i can use that on sqlite?

Comment: I have not found any option, I have used it in mongodb :(